# How to create Qr code by dots in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, cifilter

I'm trying create Qr codes and I have seen that Qr codes could be makes by dots and by figures. I know how to create simple Qr codes that are built by squares, but I don't know how to use dots like this:

[image]

I use this code to build codes easily:

```
- (CIImage *)createQRForString:(NSString *)qrString
{
// Need to convert the string to a UTF-8 encoded NSData object
NSData *stringData = [qrString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Create the filter
CIFilter *qrFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
// Set the message content and error-correction level
[qrFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
[qrFilter setValue:@"H" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];

// Send the image back
return qrFilter.outputImage;
}
```

How could I change this code to apply dots instead of squares?

Comment: CIQRCodeGenerator doesn't support this.

Comment: And.. Is there any way to generate them? thanks!

Comment: Hey, are you able to produce the same? I want same functionality with logo in middle.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the ZXingObjC framework. It lets you both scan and generate QR codes and a variety of other codes. Since it's open source you might be able to fork it and change the rendering to draw dots instead of squares.